# Fixed positioned variable height page header in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, dom

I've implemented a web page header as an AngularJS directive. The header is fixed at the top of the browser window (*position: fixed*). The height of the header varies according to it's inner content. The inner content of the header is managed by AngularJS's rendering engine. I need to update the top margin of the web page content whenever the height of the header changes. (This is how fixed headers works.)

I tried to watch the height of the header and update the top margin of the content using *$scope.$watch*. Sometimes it works, but sometimes I have to click a navigation link two times to get the right margin size. It seems that the height change is detected and handled before the header is completely updated or rendered by the browser.

My question is: Is it possible to run some code whenever the DOM manipulation invoked by Angular is completely done? Or is there any other way to make the fixed variable height page header work?

Here is the snippet of my HTML code:

```
<my-header></my-header>
<div class="content">
    ...
</div>
```

And here is the snippet of the directive's controller:

```
function MyHeaderController($scope, $element) {
    $scope.$watch(getHeaderHeight, fixContentMargin);

    function getHeaderHeight() {
        return $element[0].offsetHeight;
    };

    function fixContentMargin(newValue) {
        $element.parent()[0].querySelector('.content').style.marginTop = newValue + 'px';
        return;
    };
}
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: The header content is dynamic, right? I think you can try to adjust the margin value after the dynamic content is populated (either in `link` function when initialization, or after ajax calls which may change the height).

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to happen in a quick test I wrote: http://jsfiddle.net/yjza6x06/ if you can make it happen there then I can help you track it down. Please include more of the code that updates the my-header content.